# Suspend on Powerloss?

Tags: 12.04, suspend

My laptop battery has essentially expired - runs my laptop for about 10 min. I would like my system to suspend if power is lost. Can anyone help?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `dconf-editor` from dash and navigate to power setting

**org->gnome>settings-daemon->plugins->power**

change **sleep-inactive-battery-timeout** to some desired number of seconds
 
change **sleep-inactive-battery-type** to "suspend" 
and make sure that **use-time-for-policy** is ticked

[image]

Comment: The time method did not work on a few tries. So I tried the battery percentage one (setting percentage-action to 98). It worked a few times, but failed when I was away. Perhaps because the screensaver had popped up.

Comment: To turn off the screensaver In dconf navigate to `org>gnome>desktop>screensaver idle-activation-enabled` untick the value and save it.